# Looking for different texts with the same element name in Robot Framework

Tags: xml, robotframework

I have an XML that looks as such:

```
<vehicles>
   <car>
      <model>Accord</model>
      <color>Red</color>
   </car>
   <car>
      <model>Civic</model>
      <color>White</color>
   </car>
</vehicles>
```

I already know that there should be a Red Accord and a White Civic in the XML. I want to use the XML library of Robot Framework to make sure that "Red" and "Accord" are in the same "car" element and "White" with "Civic" in another.

I was able to get the "car" elements into a list using the Keyword `Get Elements`. However, because I cannot guarantee which "car" element is which, I cannot use the `Element Text Should Be` Keyword to see what the color is without checking what model it is first (and vice versa).

Is there a way to check that the Accord and Red are in the same car element and Civic and White are in another without using conditional logic in the test case?

Answer (score 1):

For solve your problem , I suggest you to use `LOOP` over your XML and compare to own expected data dictionary.here sample code for solve:

```
${xml}    Parse Xml    ex.xml
${expectedVehicle}=    Create Dictionary    Civic=White   Accord=Red

@{vehicles}    Get Elements    ${xml}    car
 :FOR    ${vehicle}    IN    @{vehicles}
 \    ${car}    Get Element Text    ${vehicle}    model
 \    ${color}    Get Element Text    ${vehicle}    color
 \    run keyword If   '${car}'
 \    ...     Should Be Equal As Strings     ${color}    ${expectedVehicle}[${car}]
```